# JNI Java Wrapper : How to pass byte[] argument

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I need to call a Java API from C++, using JNI. I'm trying to pass a `byte*` as below:

**Java**

```java
void OperateData(byte[] data, int dataLength)
{
   //Some Implementation
}
```

**C++**

```cpp
void OperateData(byte* data, int dataLength)
{
    JavaMethod* methodObj = getMethod(_T("OperateData"));
    JNIEnv* jniEnv = JvmManager::GetInstance()->GetJNIEnv();
    jobject jBuffer = jniEnv->CallObjectMethod(m_javaObject->getJObject(), methodObj->getJMethodID(), (jobject)data, (jint)dataLength);
}
```

This is not working. It is throwing an exception. Can you please let me know what I am doing wrong?

**Update**: I modified the C++ code as below, based on suggestions.  I'm still having the same issue.  Is anything still wrong?

```cpp
void OperateData(byte* data, int dataLength)
{
    JavaMethod* methodObj = getMethod(_T("OperateData"));
    JNIEnv* jniEnv = JvmManager::GetInstance()->GetJNIEnv();
    jbyteArray jBuff = jniEnv->NewByteArray(dataLength);
    jniEnv->SetByteArrayRegion(jBuff, 0, dataLength, (jbyte*)data);
    jobject jBuffer = jniEnv->CallObjectMethod(m_javaObject->getJObject(), methodObj->getJMethodID(), jBuff, (jint)dataLength);
    jniEnv->ReleaseByteArrayElements(jBuff,(jbyte*)data, 0);
}
```

Comment: If you're seeing an exception, you'll want to post the full stacktrace with your question

Comment: Its comming as unknown exception handled by catch(...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't simply type-cast a raw C/C++ `byte*` pointer into a `jobject` representing a Java byte array. You need to [use JNI functions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#array_operations) to:

- allocate a new Java byte array within the JVM's memory, via [`NewByteArray()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#New_PrimitiveType_Array_routines).
- then copy your raw bytes into the memory of that Java array, via either:

  - [`SetByteArrayRegion()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#Set_PrimitiveType_ArrayRegion_routines)
  - [`GetByteArrayElements()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#Get_PrimitiveType_ArrayElements_routines), `memcpy()`, and [`ReleaseByteArrayElements()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#Release_PrimitiveType_ArrayElements_routines)
- then pass that Java array to your target Java method.
- then finally release the Java array via [`DeleteLocalRef()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#DeleteLocalRef).

For example:

```
void OperateData(byte* data, int dataLength)
{
    JavaMethod* methodObj = getMethod(_T("OperateData"));
    if (!methodObj) return;
    JNIEnv* jniEnv = JvmManager::GetInstance()->GetJNIEnv();
    if (!jniEnv) return;
    jbyteArray jData = jniEnv->NewByteArray((jsize)dataLength);
    if (!jData) return;
    jniEnv->SetByteArrayRegion(jData, 0, (jsize)dataLength, (jbyte*)data);
    jniEnv->CallVoidMethod(m_javaObject->getJObject(), methodObj->getJMethodID(), jData, (jint)dataLength);
    jniEnv->DeleteLocalRef(jData);
}
```

**Update**: In comments, you say you changed the Java code to return a `byte[]` instead of `void`. If so, you need to adjust the C++ code accordingly, eg:

```
void OperateData(byte* data, int dataLength)
{
    JavaMethod* methodObj = getMethod(_T("OperateData"));
    if (!methodObj) return;
    JNIEnv* jniEnv = JvmManager::GetInstance()->GetJNIEnv();
    if (!jniEnv) return;
    jbyteArray jData = jniEnv->NewByteArray((jsize)dataLength);
    if (!jData) return;
    jniEnv->SetByteArrayRegion(jData, 0, (jsize)dataLength, (jbyte*)data);
    jobject jBuffer = jniEnv->CallObjectMethod(m_javaObject->getJObject(), methodObj->getJMethodID(), jData, (jint)dataLength);
    if (jBuffer) jniEnv->DeleteLocalRef(jBuffer);
    jniEnv->DeleteLocalRef(jData);
}
```

Comment: Modified the JNI as below based on your suggestion:                                     void OperateData(byte* data,int dataLength)
{
    JavaMethod* methodObj = getMethod(_T("OperateData"));
    JNIEnv* jniEnv = JvmManager::GetInstance()->GetJNIEnv();
    jbyteArray jBuff = jniEnv->NewByteArray(dataLength);                       
   jniEnv->SetByteArrayRegion(jBuff,0,dataLength,(jbyte*)data);    
   jobject jBuffer = jniEnv->CallObjectMethod(m_javaObject->getJObject(), methodObj->getJMethodID(), jBuff,(jint)dataLength);
}

Comment: @LokanathNayak close. You are not doing error handling, and you are not releasing the Java array when done

Comment: `JObject` should be `jobject`. See the edit history. That's the only thing I edited, and it isn't there now.

Comment: @EJP you made an edit while I was still making my own edits. Your edit was lost. I re-applied it

Comment: No problem, I can see how it happened.

Comment: He should not call `ReleaseByteArrayElements()`. Incorrect advice.

Comment: @EJP `ReleaseByteArrayElements()` MUST be used IF `GetByteArrayElements()` is used to access the underlying array memory and the array is altered via that pointer (which it would be in this situation). I'm not using that approach in my example, but that doesn't make it bad advice. It is a perfectly valid approach. Just a different one.

Comment: Hi Remy, I used exactly your example. just added a return at the end since my Java API returns byte[]. Still I am seeing the crash at jobject jBuffer = jniEnv->CallObjectMethod(m_javaObject->getJObject(), methodObj->getJMethodID(), jData, (jint)dataLength);                                                                  The JAVA API is as: byte[] OperateData(byte[] data, int dataLength)
{
   //Some Implementation
}

Comment: Also the Method I have added in JNI as: jmethodID jMethod = jniEnv->GetMethodID(m_javaClass->getJClass(), "oprateData", "([B;I)[B");                
 Is there any issue at this place

Comment: @LokanathNayak what are you `return`ing exactly? Not the `jobject` that `CallObjectMethod()` returns, I hope. You need to stop posting important details in comments and instead edit your question to post them. Also, your `GetMethodID` call is wrong, it should be `GetMethodID(m_javaClass->getJClass(), "OperateData", "([BI)[B")`.

Answer (score 4):

```
JavaMethod* methodObj = getMethod(_T("OperateData"));
// ...
jobject jBuffer = jniEnv->CallObjectMethod(m_javaObject->getJObject(), methodObj->getJMethodID(), (jobject)data,(jint)dataLength);
// ...
jniEnv->ReleaseByteArrayElements(jBuff,(jbyte*)data, 0);
```

None of this makes any sense.

1. JNI method signatures contain parameter and return type information, as given by the output of `javap -s`. So the JNI signature of the Java method is definitely not merely `"OperateData"`.
2. So your `methodObj` must be null, or contain a `jmethodID` that is zero, and this alone is sufficient to explain your problem.
3. There is an appalling lack of error-checking in this code. The result of *every* JNI call must be error-checked.
4. The Java method you're calling is `void`, so it doesn't return a `jobject`.
5. The Java method you're calling is `void`, so you should be using [`CallVoidMethod()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#Call_type_Method_routines).
6. You need to convert the C++ `char *data` array to a `jbytearray`, using `NewByteArray()`, and populate it using the appropriate [JNI Array Methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#New_PrimitiveType_Array_routines).
7. You are calling `ReleaseByteArrayElements()` incorrectly. You don't need to call it at all here, but when you do call it, it is called with a pointer obtained via `GetByteArrayElements()`. Not with your own data.
8. After the call you should [delete the local reference to the `jbytearray`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#DeleteLocalRef), if you're finished with it.